# Is using an array inside an anonymous class thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety

I'm trying to determine if the following java methods are thread safe:

```
public Object calledByMultipleThreads() {
    final Object[] item = new Object[1];

    if (!EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
        try {
            EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    helperMethod(item)
                }
            });
        } catch (InterruptedException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
            // logging...
        }
    } else {
        helperMethod(item)

    }

    return item[0];
}

private void helperMethod(Object[] item) {
    item[0] = new Object();
}
```

I know that `final Object[] item = new Object[1]` is a workaround (since something like `final Object item` couldn't be modified inside the `Runnable`). And since `invokeAndWait` is used, `item[0]` is set before it's referenced by the `return`, but my fear is that a caller thread (that's not the EDT) might not see the update to the `item` array, and return `null`. Is this possible? Is there any way I can test its safety?

Comment: When in doubt, and while you need the array just as a container to pass an object back, you can always use an AtomicReference. I have developed the habit to use it as a generic container to pass back a result from anonymous callbacks (and similar ocasions), even if I don't need the atomic aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the details of how `invokeAndWait` is implemented, all actions happening within the `Runnable` *happen-before* the return of control to the caller of `invokeAndWait`:

```
1233  synchronized (lock) {
1234      Toolkit.getEventQueue().postEvent(event);
1235      while (!event.isDispatched()) {
1236          lock.wait();
1237      }
1238  }
```

In other words, what you are doing is safe. On the other hand, there's no way to ensure such a guarantee by testing :)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays aren't automatically thread-safe any more than non-`final` instance fields are.

However, here there is not a thread safety issue. There will be a *happens-before* between the assignment within `EventQueueinvokeAndWait` and that method returning.

Note `invokeAndWait` is liable to cause (effective) deadlocks. It's much better to use `EventQueue.invokeLater` and a similar method to post back to your non-EDT thread.